# Why use Third Party Push Notification Providers over GCM

Tags: android, push-notification

I am an android developer ....have made a few apps...but for the first time had a chance to implement push notifications for one of my apps... After looking for a number of solutions including Amazon SNS, Pushbots, Pushy, Parse etc.I was wondering on why there are a lot of popular third party services...

If they implement the same GCM. GCM also provides a dashboard with tracking and topic based notifications.

Is there any disadvantage if I am using GCM directly. **Also a big question... most of the push services only offer sending notification to apps**... what if I need to trigger notification from my android app. Does GCM supports this. What are the best solutions for implementing this.

Comment: Google pulled out from China a while ago, so you have to use a third party service for push notification if your user is in China. (just one example)

Comment: That's okay... My question is : Why should I pay other service providers who use GCM only... and there are many who pay.

Comment: Just to clarify - Pushy does not use GCM. It maintains its own socket connection, which improves reliability. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Comment: @EladNava If Pushy maintains its own socket connection then how it does so on devices running 8.0 and above. Even for MQTT messages you need to have a constant connection to the server, if I am not wrong. I don't even see a notification saying that a foreground service is running.

Comment: Hi @Bijoy, on Android 8.0 and newer, we make use of the new JobService interface to maintain an MQTT connection in the background while staying compliant with Android O's Background Execution Limits: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService

Comment: @EladNava just a follow up question. As far as I know there is a time limit for JobService (most probably 15 minutes). So, what if a notification arrives after the said time limit, do you reschedule the Job? But according to docs the minimum schedule between two jobs is 15 minutes. what if when the app enters the doze mode? if you are rescheduling the job then what about battery life?